# Set Custom "Star review rating" as required entry

Tags: magento-1.9, review, ratings

I'm using Clickable star ratings for my e-commerce web site. I have followed the instructions provided within this tutorial:

http://blog.youbility.de/en/clickable-star-ratings-in-magento/

Now I'm trying to accomplished that star rating is required entry. So when I use the class name "required-entry" in the following code of line:

```
<input type="radio" name="ratings[<?php echo $_rating->getId() ?>]" id="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php echo $_option->getValue() ?>" value="<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>" class="radio rating-input" />
```

just at the end of the code where is says: **class=radio rading-input** i have made the change so it looks: **class=radio rading-input required-entry**

Now star rating becomes required-entry, but it becomes required-entry for all the five starts - and i need to make five stars required-entry as one field.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did same thing but the different way. Instead of putting `required-entry` class to `radio`, I add new validation rule to that form.

Please put below code in your review form page, it might be work for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var dataForm = new VarienForm("review-form", true);

    Validation.addAllThese(
            [
                ['validate-rating', '<?php echo $this->__('Please select one of each of the ratings above') ?>', function (v) {
                            return false;

                }]
            ]
            );
    //]]>
</script>
```

Here is the output of validation:
[image]

Let me know if you have query for the same.

---

For single rating option:

[image]

Comment: this works perfect. Thanks Jayesh very much.

Comment: Great, happy coding ... :)

Comment: Hi again. Sorry my bed. I just noticed that when I do not select star rating it asks me to select one of five start - which is OK. But. than again, when I select one star, it still keeps me asking to select the star? Any idea?

Comment: How many rating options are enabled in your store, it will prompt you for all required rating option in my case it is `Quantity`, `Price` & `Value`. I need to select star for each rating.

Comment: Where is only one option in my case, which is the Value. Thanks.

Comment: Its worked for single option as well, please see second screen shot attached in answer.

Comment: I sow your example. But in my case it simple do not work. Wired. I will try to reset all the changes and see if there is something I made wrong. If you want i can provide you with my code which I use?

Comment: Is your site accessible to me, if so please provide URL.

Comment: Sorry it is not. it will be tomorrow. Than i can provide you the link? OK? Thanks :)